# Did not receive investor badge, does the bounty need to expire/be awarded?

Tags: support, bounty-badges

I offered a bounty on [What's the best tool to manage documentation for Restful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/436506/751151)

Does the bounty need to expire or be awarded before the investor badge is awarded?

Comment: I did receive the Altruist badge when I awarded the bounty, fairly promptly too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the badge is only awarded if the "someone else" exists. In this case, your bounty is on a question asked by a now-deleted user. It's not exactly something that's simple to test, but without interjection from the team, that's my conclusion.

It is generally awarded within one day of assigning the bounty. Awarding the bounty is only necessary to get the Altruist badge. Which I don't know whether or not the user's deletion will affect it, but I guess we can see in about 10 hours.

Comment: Did the point about the user being now-deleted turn out to be the case?  I'm curious because I'm in the same situation with a bounty I've created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290152/project-reference-in-rdlc-reportviewer-report  (I'm also terribly curious what will happen if the question goes unanswered, but I'm sure there's a Meta question around here somewhere for that.)

Comment: You were right, but [Nick is fixing this now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131687/131713).

Comment: And, fixed. Colin's account is now showing Investor.

Answer (score 0):

Just needs to be offered.  <strike>I would suggest waiting a little longer, not all badges are awarded real-time.</strike>

**Edit**: I see that it has been around for a while.  You should have gotten notification about this badge by now.

Comment: Fair enough, it's been almost 7 days, and the award is about to expire.