# Got Altruist badge but not Investor badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, bounties

I offered a bounty on [another person's question on Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/how-does-facebook-guess-results-when-you-search-for-someone) yesterday, but did not receive the Investor badge.

When I awarded the bounty today, I did receive the Altruist badge. I still have not received the Investor badge.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a bug in the badge related to owner-less questions (`<> NULL` comparison in SQL, ultimately).

It'll be fixed in a build going out momentarily.

Comment: and we will recieve the badge at that point of time?

Comment: @RishabhPoddar - you'll get it as soon as it runs (up to 5 minutes after).

Comment: 5 mins? It been more than 5 hrs. 5 minutes is what every usual badge takes.

Comment: @RishabhPoddar Nick has to push a build. Badges will run after that.

Comment: @RishabhPoddar - check [your badges screen](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/19533/rishabh-poddar?tab=badges&sort=recent) :)

Answer (score 1):

The user who asked that question, "user8144," appears to be deleted. You may never receive the Investor badge for that particular bounty.

A similar issue was reported at [Did not receive investor badge, does the bounty need to expire/be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94952/131713). Colin never did get his Investor badge.

Comment: but then I got the badge other batch when I manually awarded the bounty? - Now that's a contradiction to your answer.

Comment: I never said you wouldn't get Altruist. Where's the contradiction?

Comment: So, because of the deleted OP of the question I will never get Invester; but it does not affects the Altruist at all? Why different rules for fairly similar badges?

Comment: Thanks to Nick's fix, Rishabh and Colin both have their official shiny Investor badges. I'm leaving this answer here mostly for the link.